# Motorcycle auxiliary light wiring

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, lights

I'm adding auxiliary lights to my motorcycle (Suzuki DRZ400). My goal is to have a switch that turns the lights on, but also so the lights can't be turned on without the ignition turned on. There isn't an aux connector to get power from.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do without splicing the harness (at the ignition switch, or at the low beam)?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely will have to splice the harness. I would also advice you to have a look on ThumperTalk. Everything that has to do with drz400's has been done and documented on there.

Comment: If it's been documented over there, why not bring the information over here? Just provide a link to give credit and you'd be golden. Would completely make this answer awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Before you stick lights on that little bike check to be sure your alternator can handle it.   Small bikes like that only have a charging system heavey enough to deal with starting up and running the normal lights.  You might find your battery dead running those auxiliary lights on a long ride at night when you go to start it up after a late meal.on the road.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what model your DRZ400 is, but it should have lights already. What you're asking is very doable although I don't see how without splicing.

So if you don't mind splicing, what you'll need to do is splice into your low beam wire (should be the yellow one of the yellow, black, red) and add a switch to that. If you're just adding a light pod or two or perhaps some LED light strips you should be fine with your alternator and all that, but you'll start to push it if you do multiple light bars and light strips.